# Creating a matrix from a vector with a specific indexing without a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, indexing, vectorization

I have a vector and a matrix like this:

```
v = [0.3 -3 3 -2 7 6]
INDEX = [1 3; 3 5; 4 6]
```

`INDEX` is a matrix that indicates the first and last element on `v` that the `RESULT` row must have. I'm making sure that every interval in `INDEX`, i.e., 
`1 to 3`, `3 to 5` and `4 to 6`, has the same length so every row in `RESULT` matrix has the same length.

I want to obtain a matrix like this:

```
RESULT = [0.3 -3  3; 
            3 -2  7; 
           -2  7  6]
```

How to do this without a `for` loop?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: How exactly do you get from `INDEX`, which is `3 x 2` to `RESULT`, which is `3 x 3`?

Comment: @excaza He means from 1 **to** 3 (i.e. 1,2,3)

Comment: yes, @MehrdadZandigohar is right, i'm sorry if it's misleading

Comment: I'm making sure that the intervals have the same length, so every row has the same length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Determine the difference between last value and first value of each row of `INDEX`. Generate the required indices using this difference and then extract the required values using those indices.

```
idx = [INDEX(:,1) INDEX(:,1)+[1:INDEX(1,end)-INDEX(1,1)]];  %Generating the indices
%for finding indices in <= R2016a, use this:
%idx = [INDEX(:,1) bsxfun(@plus, INDEX(:,1), [1:INDEX(1,end)-INDEX(1,1)])];
RESULT = v(idx);
```

Comment: This is good, thank you! (Unfortunately it still takes more time than a for loop).

Comment: @ViniciusM I don't expect indexing to be slower than anything. How are you timing it and with what data size? Also include your code with that loop in your original post

Comment: v has 2400000 elements, and INDEX has 114 rows, the RESULT is 114 x 16832 in the end. I'm timing with a simple tic toc.

Comment: @ViniciusM Time it with [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). `tic` `toc` is for getting a rough idea about time,

Comment: @ViniciusM can you share your for loop?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer:**

RESULT=v(cell2mat(arrayfun(@colon, INDEX(:,1), INDEX(:,2), 'Uniform', false)))

**Here is how it works:**

You should first make a matrix which contains all indexes of `INDEX` matrix.

The code below makes a cell of all indexes (and not ONLY the beginning and the end of interval):

`cell_index=arrayfun(@colon, INDEX(:,1), INDEX(:,2), 'Uniform', false)`

Then you should convert it from cell to matrix by `cell2mat` function:

`mat_index=cell2mat(cell_index)`

Finally, you substitute the indexes into the `v` vector:

`RESULT=v(mat_index)`

Comment: The OP wanted to do it ***without*** a loop. `arrayfun` is itself a loop

Comment: I mean, it's a good answer, thank you. But, it takes more time than doing a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in this case would be

```
RESULT=v([INDEX(:,1) INDEX(:,1)+1 INDEX(:,2)])
```

In case you might have spans in the index arrays covering exact middle indexes:

```
RESULT=v([INDEX(:,1) (INDEX(:,1)+INDEX(:,2))/2 INDEX(:,2)])
```

In order to provide working and general enough solution, you should provide the constraints that index matrix can have.